# How to pass POST data to my Slim webapp in AWS Lambda through API Gateway

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I know it's not the best practice, but I uploaded my Slim project (PHP) to a Lambda function following this very good tutorial by Chris White: https://cwhite.me/hosting-a-laravel-application-on-aws-lambda/

My API Gateway has a proxy resource and uses the Lambda Proxy integration.

I can access all of my project's pages just fine, but when I try to submit a form, I cannot access the input values in my Controllers.
 (e.g. *$request->getParam('email')* is NULL) All input values from my form are NULL.

In fact, when I tried

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

It returned an empty array.

In my local project, I tried dumping the **$request** object and found the input values from my form in ***bodyParsed***. I did the same with my project uploaded in AWS Lambda, but the ***bodyParsed*** there is an empty array.

Why is GET working but my POSTs aren't? What am I missing?

A detailed explanation would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the Mapping Template with the Api Gateway?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

ex.:

```
{
    "name" : "$input.params('name')",
    "body" : $input.json('$') 
}
```

Comment: I've read about that, but I am not quite sure where to put it. I've enabled the "Use Lambda Proxy integration" and the Body Mapping Templates isn't available to me.

Comment: Hello, in Api Gateway choose your resource and method -> 'Integration Request' -> 'Body Mapping Templates' -> 'Add mapping template' with 'Content-Type' = 'application/json' -> add the json mapping. Try it.

Comment: I'm a bit lost. I used a proxy resource so that my routes.php will handle everything. I also have Lambda Proxy Integration enabled, so 'Body Mapping Templates' isn't available. I'm sorry if you think I am misunderstanding you. I am still new to AWS. You can see how I got my Slim project to work in Lambda here:  https://cwhite.me/hosting-a-laravel-application-on-aws-lambda/

Comment: I suggest to make a new empty lambda just for testing, just for you the parameters passing in the api gateway and arriving in the lambda. So you understand the workings. Here's a cool example at nodejs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

Comment: I have no problem in passing parameters to lambda. My problem is passing those parameters to my PHP project in Lambda. Thank you though :)

Comment: You can't use mapping templates with lambda proxy. You can find from the docs the format of input json that'll be passed to the lambda function http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format

I think the issue is with the php connector you seem to be using. https://cwhite.me/hosting-a-laravel-application-on-aws-lambda/ has been deleted now.